# First Click Fails, Second Click is Successful on Ajax Call • JQuery / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an Ajax call, which posts to a PHP and when complete, reloads a `div`.

Button (Ajax Trigger)

```
<div class='btn btn-danger pull-right group-action' data-action='handle=" . $folder_name . "&action=delete_group' style=' margin:5px 10px 5px 5px;'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>
    <span> Delete Group</span>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click', '.group-action', function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
        var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server/php/delete_action.php",
            cache: false,
            data: action + "&random=" + randnum,
            success: function(){
                $('#show_groups').load('server/php/show_groups.php');
            }

        }); 

    });

</script>
```

PHP Page (delete_action.php)

```
<?php

    $dir_base = 'files/';

    $handle = $dir_base . $_POST['handle'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    function delete_all_images($dirname) {
        foreach(glob($dirname.'/*.*') as $v){
        unlink($v);
        }
    }

    function delete_group($dirname) {
       if (is_dir($dirname))
          $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
       if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
       while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
             if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                unlink($dirname."/".$file);
             else
                delete_group($dirname.'/'.$file);    
          }
       }
       closedir($dir_handle);
       rmdir($dirname);
       return true;
    }

    if( (isset($action)) && (!empty($action)) && (isset($handle)) && (!empty($handle)) ){
        $doit = $action($handle);
        eval($doit);
    }

?>
```

What is happening is when I click once on the trigger button, the action of the PHP does what it should, yet the Load function on success doesn't trigger, but if I click the button a second time, it works correctly and the success function runs.

Comment: what logging are you doing on the server side?  How are you tracing your PHP code to see what the values are and if they are what you expect?

Comment: I don't see you defined `action`. `data:"action="+ action + "&random=" + randnum,` Also where do you get `handle` variable?

Comment: As far as logging, I was running a console.log() for all the client side actions. For the server side, the php is deleting folders and files on my server which I see happening on the first click.

Comment: @thescientist Edited Question - Added the Button Trigger

Comment: Are you sure that your `delete_action.php` script works correctly and returns status `HTTP 200`? Otherwise the `success` handler would not be called. You can try adding a `complete` handler that would output some debug message. This handler gets called in any case.

Comment: @VIDesignz I was saying that you should add logging to your PHP code.  I think you will find some things are not what you expect.

Comment: @thescientist I added echos throughout and they printed every step all the way to the end. I've run the PHP Manually without the ajax call and all was well too.

Comment: @Dmitry I know it works correctly, I have run it separately, though I don't know how to tell if it returns that status?

Comment: @Naumche suggested adding `async: "false"` to my ajax call, and it did the trick...yet I am unfamiliar with how/why this would fix the issue...any explanations would be appreciated :)

Comment: @VIDesignz for the actual status, I would monitor the networks tab in your browsers developer tools.  With it open and then initiating the request, you should see everything sent to and from the server; headers, POST body, status, etc

Comment: @thescientist Oh man, thank you for that, I had no idea about that tool.  Awesome.  What is mind blowing is that it is working correctly now even without `async: 'false'` with no other changes...over an hour and a half and it just magically starts working.

Comment: @thescientist To note, all the status' were successful...

Comment: @VIDesignz glad its working.  If anything my money was on that fact that there was no key/value for action.  i.e.  data: 'action=' + action + '&randnum=' + randnum

Comment: @thescientist The `action` key/value is prebuilt on the button using an attribute `data-action='handle=directory&action=delete'` so it was there...my variable creations get out of hand at times..haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use async: false, on ajax function,

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server/php/delete_action.php",
            cache: false,
            data: action + "&random=" + randnum,
            success: function(){
                $('#show_groups').load('server/php/show_groups.php');
            },
            async: "false",

        });
```

Thanks,
Naumche

Comment: I added this and it worked, then I removed it and it still worked...not sure why still. I'll give you the nice green check mark anyway :)